# My `npm run serve` for Vue 3 project appears to be broke missing require stack

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, package.json

When i tried to run `npm run serve` it shows like this...

```
 INFO  Starting development server...
 ERROR  Error: Cannot find module 'caniuse-lite/data/features/css-unicode-bidi'
Require stack:
- D:\VueJs Acad\M7 - VueCLI\first-app\node_modules\autoprefixer\data\prefixes.js
- D:\VueJs Acad\M7 - VueCLI\first-app\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js
- D:\VueJs Acad\M7 - VueCLI\first-app\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\config\css.js
- D:\VueJs Acad\M7 - VueCLI\first-app\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js
- D:\VueJs Acad\M7 - VueCLI\first-app\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js
Error: Cannot find module 'caniuse-lite/data/features/css-unicode-bidi'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDVNq.jpg)

Comment: The library `caniuse-lite` may not be updated CSS property `unicode-bidi`. Try to update the library and let me know the result

Comment: https://github.com/browserslist/caniuse-lite/issues/102

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem,
After checking, it is found that the caniuse-lite package has an updated version, The css-unicode-bidi.js file is missing. I found the previous version from the official repository, download it, unzip it, find the css-unicode-bidi.js file, and copy it to the node_modules/caniuse-lite/data/features/

url: https://github.com/browserslist/caniuse-lite/releases/tag/1.0.30001393